# Same Xmonad.hs configuration breaks under the same version on different computers

Tags: xmonad, xmobar

I have the exact same Xmonad.hs configuration on two different Linux installations, and while it's working fine on the computer I installed it to the first time, it is causing errors on the second installation. Here is [the configuration file:](https://raw.github.com/lelandbatey/configDebDev/master/.xmonad/xmonad.hs)

```
import XMonad
import XMonad.Hooks.DynamicLog
import XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks
import XMonad.Util.Run(spawnPipe)
import System.IO

main = do
  xmproc <- spawnPipe "~/.cabal/bin/xmobar ~/.xmobarrc"
  xmonad $ defaultConfig
    { manageHook = manageDocks <+> manageHook defaultConfig
      , layoutHook = avoidStruts  $  layoutHook defaultConfig
      , logHook = dynamicLogWithPP xmobarPP
        { ppOutput = hPutStrLn xmproc
        , ppTitle = xmobarColor "green" "" . shorten 80
        }
    , terminal    = "urxvt"
    , modMask     = mod1Mask
    , borderWidth = 1 --was "3"
    , focusedBorderColor = "#4099FF"
    , normalBorderColor = "#474747"
    }
```

And here is the error that it results in on the second computer(mirrored at nacr.us/media/xmonad.errors):

```
xmonad.hs:11:20:
    Couldn't match expected type `ManageHook'
                with actual type `xmonad-0.10:XMonad.Core.ManageHook'
    In the first argument of `(<+>)', namely `manageDocks'
    In the `manageHook' field of a record
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `defaultConfig
         {manageHook = manageDocks <+> manageHook defaultConfig,
          layoutHook = avoidStruts $ layoutHook defaultConfig,
          logHook = dynamicLogWithPP
                      (xmobarPP
                         {ppOutput = hPutStrLn xmproc,
                          ppTitle = xmobarColor "green" "" . shorten 80}),
          terminal = "urxvt", modMask = mod1Mask, borderWidth = 1,
          focusedBorderColor = "#4099FF", normalBorderColor = "#474747"}'
```

Additionally, both installations of xmonad are on identical versions of Ubuntu 12.04, and the installed versions of xmonad are identical (according to `apt-cache show xmonad`).

Is there something that I'm forgetting about this? I cannot for the life of me figure out what is the problem.

Additionally, here's my dotfiles repo with all the relevant files: https://github.com/lelandbatey/configDebDev

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you have two versions of `xmonad` installed (xmonad-0.10 plus some other version), and they are conflicting for some reason. You might try `ghc-pkg check` to verify that you don't have any broken packages. Next, I would remove xmonad and reinstall it, using your package manager (apt-get?).

Comment: This was it for me. Running ghc-pkg check revealed that version 0.11 was also installed, while my config files were written for 0.10. I found the script provided by Simon Michael here quite helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961604/fixing-issues-noted-by-ghc-pkg-check