# ghci, linking failed on different libraries

Tags: haskell, ghci, winghci

I try to use the [Graphalyze](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Graphalyze) library, installed by the standard way `cabal install graphalyze`. When I import any modules from this package, I face with a trouble.
My project normally loading into WinGHCi, but when I try to use any function, I see:

```
Loading package bktrees-0.3.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package filepath-1.3.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package old-time-1.1.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package directory-1.1.0.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package colour-2.3.3 ... linking ... done.
Loading package dlist-0.5 ... linking ... done.
Loading package polyparse-1.8 ... linking ... done.
Loading package process-1.1.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package temporary-1.1.2.4 ... linking ... done.
Loading package wl-pprint-text-1.1.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package graphviz-2999.16.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package network-2.3.1.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package HTTP-4000.2.5 ... linking ... done.
Loading package base64-bytestring-1.0.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package blaze-builder-0.3.1.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package blaze-markup-0.5.1.5 ... linking ... done.
Loading package blaze-html-0.5.1.3 ... linking ... done.
Loading package List-0.5.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package extensible-exceptions-0.1.1.4 ... linking ... done.
Loading package utf8-string-0.3.7 ... linking ... done.
Loading package hexpat-0.20.3 ... linking ... done.
Loading package syb-0.3.7 ... linking ... done.
Loading package hs-bibutils-5.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package pretty-1.1.1.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package json-0.7 ... linking ... done.
Loading package pandoc-types-1.10 ... linking ... done.
Loading package citeproc-hs-0.3.8 ... linking ... done.
Loading package data-default-class-0.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package data-default-instances-base-0.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package data-default-instances-containers-0.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package data-default-instances-dlist-0.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package data-default-instances-old-locale-0.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package data-default-0.5.3 ... linking ... done.
Loading package regex-base-0.93.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package regex-pcre-builtin-0.94.4.7.8.31 ... linking ... ghc: unable to load package `regex-pcre-builtin-0.94.4.7.8.31'
```

If I try again without reloading, I see only one string, but on differ library!:

```
Loading package bktrees-0.3.1 ... linking ... ghc: unable to load package `bktrees-0.3.1'
```

What is the problem?

I use `WinGHCi 1.0.6` and ghc version `7.4.2`, in `ghci` i have the same problem.

---

**Upd**: `runghc` results `` `HSregex-pcre-builtin-0.94.4.7.8.31.o: unknown symbol __imp__pcre _compile' ``

Comment: If you use `runghc` to run your program do you get the same problem? Have you tried something like `ghc-pkg check` to verify if the packages are with problem? I also would recommend you to [uninstall](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Cabal-Install) the packages and reinstall them to see if the problem persists.

Comment: `runghc` results `HSregex-pcre-builtin-0.94.4.7.8.31.o: unknown symbol ``__imp__pcre
_compile'``

Comment: Given it, I'd try: (1) `ghc-pkg check` to see if any package is reported as broken (probably `regex-pcre-builtin` will be reported); (2) I would try to fix the problem following the instructions from [`cabal-install` wiki page](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Cabal-Install), [GHC documentation on (broken) packages](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/packages.html#package-ids), [Stackoverflow related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7961896/635669). In a nutshell, I would `ghc-pkg unregister regex-pcre-builtin`, `cabal update` and `cabal install regex-pcre-builtin`.