# Error Depedency PHP

Tags: php, web, freebsd

After I upgrade php53 to php56 emerge several error on my freebsd 8.4, this error message from `pkg check -Bd`

```
pkg: fstat() failed for(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/xmlbuilder.py): No such file or directory
pkg: fstat() failed for(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementPath.py): No such file or directory
pkg: fstat() failed for(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/__init__.py): No such file or directory
pkg: fstat() failed for(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/cElementTree.py): No such file or directory
pkg: fstat() failed for(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/parsers/__init__.py): No such file or directory
pkg: fstat() failed for(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/parsers/expat.py): No such file or directory
pkg: fstat() failed for(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/__init__.py): No such file or directory
pkg: fstat() failed for(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/handler.py): No such file or directory
pkg: fstat() failed for(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/xmllib.py): No such file or directory
Checking all packages: 100%
gio-fam-backend has a missing dependency: perl5.14

>>> Missing package dependencies were detected.
>>> Found 1 issue(s) in the package database.

pkg: No packages available to install matching 'perl5.14' have been found in the repositories
>>> Summary of actions performed:

perl5.14 dependency failed to be fixed

>>> There are still missing dependencies.
>>> You are advised to try fixing them manually.

>>> Also make sure to check 'pkg updating' for known issues.
```

There is several error after I check depedency. I don't how to fix it because I have been install perl5.20 and python. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Don't see a question here. You fix the missing package dependencies...

Comment: *No packages available to install matching 'perl5.14' have been found in the repositories** - Could you not build from source? Note, this doesn't seem a programming question, would be better suited to one of the server or linux stackexchange sites.

Answer (score 0):

> That it is not finding Subversion is either because it has not been installed, or the package database has not been converted with pkg2ng. See http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/pkgng-intro.html.

Google keywords :)
https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/pkg-check-broken.44280/

Also, question already been asked.  [Fixing issues noted by ghc-pkg check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961604/fixing-issues-noted-by-ghc-pkg-check)